# Using pyenv and I can't find oauth2client module installed through pip

Tags: python, pip, google-oauth, google-api-client, pyenv

I'm getting the error `ImportError: No module named oauth2client` when I try to run a Python script that uses `google-api-python-client`

I had a lot going on in this computer in terms of Python installations, but as far as I can tell things look consistent now:

```
$ which python
/Users/bani/.pyenv/shims/python
$ which pip
/Users/bani/.pyenv/shims/pip
$ pyenv which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ pip install --upgrade oauth2client
Requirement already up-to-date: oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

`/Users/bani/.pyenv/shims` is also the first thing in my `PATH`.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you run the script? `python script` or just `script`? In the latter case what is the shebang line in the script?

Comment: `python script` :(

Comment: What are the versions? `python --version` and `pip --version`. Does  `python -c 'import oauth2client'` work from command line?

Comment: @phd `$ python --version`
`Python 2.7.12`
`$ pip --version`
`pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)`
`$ python -c 'import oauth2client'`
`ImportError: No module named oauth2client`

Comment: Is there `oauth2client` directory in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`? Directory `oauth2client-4.1.2.dist-info`? If there is the latter but not the former remove the latter and reinstall `oauth2client`.

Comment: I have both directories.

Comment: Ok, I tried a pip uninstall followed by a pip install and that seemed to fix oauth! Now it's the next lib that is broken... any advice to clean up everything at once?

Comment: Nevermind, I just needed to do it with one more lib. Thanks for your help!